# Flask-Testing module no such test method error

Tags: python, testing, flask

Coming here after trying both #python and #pocoo. I'm writing a unit test for a flask app, and wanted to test for redirection. The official flask tutorials don't have anything about that, so I tried to use this: http://packages.python.org/Flask-Testing/

Here's the code I have so far to test the tutorial application (the app code is here: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr/ )

```
from flaskext.testing import TestCase
import flaskr
from flask import Flask

class FlaskrTest(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        return app

    def test_add_entry(self, title, text):
        resp = app.post('/add', data=dict(title='blah',
            text='Blooh'), follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertRedirects(resp, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTest = FlaskrTest()
    myTest.test_add_entry()
```

and here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskr_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    myTest = FlaskrTest()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 185, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.FlaskrTest'>: runTest
```

I'll appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to run your tests is to use `unittest.main` for collecting tests because the `flask.ext.testing.TestCase` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`. All other test collectors like `nose` with support for `unittest.TestCase` classes should work.

A simple example with `unittest.main` looks like this:

```
import unittest

# Here your TestCases

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

`unittest` will discover all your test cases and test methods but notice that the class and methods names must start with `test`.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of Flask-Testing.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I eventually tested using unittest, just as you have suggested here. But the problem that I was having was with the Flask-Testing module (which doesn't mention the unittest module), as I said above. As mentioned in the API docs which I linked, I created the app in the create_app method, and provided the test in the `test_add_entry method`, which begins with `test`. Creating an instance of the class and then running the method is not running that test. That was the problem I was having. :)

Comment: I added more special information about Flask-Testing into my answer.

Comment: I was really frustrated for the lack of documentation in Flask-Testing. A tutorial would be really useful. I ran into the `runTest` error and could not find a solution. I’m currently using plain unittest.main() but would love to use Flask-Testing.